# Add attribute attributes while appending a js file using headscript()

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

This is my first time working with php. I was trying to optimize js in a website where I saw `headscript()` to append js file.

```
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js');
```

In this I am trying to add an attribute the script tag appended

```
$this->headScript()->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js',
```

I also tried

```
$this->headScript()->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js',$attrs = array("async" => "true"))
```

array("async" => "true"));

php portion in the file

```
    <?php
    $this->headScript()->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);
    echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js', $attrs = array("async" => "true"));
    ?>
```

I expected output to be

```
<script async="true" src="/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Instead I got

```
<script type="Array" src="/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

How to solve it? I was not able to find any samples where attributes are added via `headscript();`

Comment: It would be better if you contacted the author of the php script to find the correct syntax. You haven't supplied enough information for use to work on.

Comment: @jeff: I was not able to find any. I posted this question here hoping anyone who may have tried this would help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the attributes as the **third** argument

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile(
  '/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js', 
  null, 
  array('async' => 'true', 'foo' => 'bar')
);
```

`null` here is the 'type' attribute, which will default to `text/javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `Zend` framework. If so please refer [HeadScript Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-script.html)

You need to pass the attributes as `$attrs = array()`

```
appendFile($src, $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = array())
```

So your code should be

**UPDATED CODE**

```
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js',  $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = array("async" => "true"));
```

instead of

```
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js', array("async" => "true"));
```

Comment: Still the same thing happens

Comment: Can you paste the code for ``$this->headScript()->appendFile()``

Comment: You added the ``function invocation code``, but ``function definition code`` is required as this does not seem to a standard API.

Comment: Could you help me with this. This my first time with `php` and I was not able to find a complete code with `headscript` usage.

Comment: -1 You posted the correct method signature but your examples both try to use the `$type` argument to include the attributes. The attributes array should be passed as the *3rd* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary attributes are disabled by default. To allow such attributes, you can enable them via the setAllowArbitraryAttributes() method:

```
$this->headScript()->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);
```

Then

```
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/image-gallery/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js',  null, array("async" => "true"));
```